# Send one email that contains all rows in an Excel filter

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

This VBA code auto sends emails from Excel.

What can I do to send one email with data in different rows?

The code is taking individual rows and and sending email but I want to filter it by same information located in different rows and send all those rows in one email.

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As 
 String)
'
' SendEmail Macro
'

'    
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

olMail.To = what_address
olMail.Subject = subject_line
olMail.Body = mail_body
olMail.Send

End Sub


Sub SendMassEmail()

row_number = 6

Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
Dim mail_body_message As String
Dim Invoice_no As String
Dim Customer_name As String
Dim Due_Date As String
Dim Foreign_amount As String

mail_body_message = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("N7").Value
Invoice_no = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("D" & row_number).Value
Customer_name = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("E" & row_number).Value
Due_Date = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("F" & row_number).Value
Foreign_amount = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("J" & row_number).Value
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_Invoice_here", 
Invoice_no)
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_customer_here", 
Customer_name)
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_DueDate_here", 
Due_Date)
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_ 
ForeignAmount_here", Foreign_amount)

MsgBox mail_body_message
Call SendEmail(Worksheets("Sheet").Range("K" & row_number), "Outstanding 
Invoices", mail_body_message)

Loop Until row_number = 227
MsgBox "Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post an Example of your data \ spreadsheet

Comment: its basically a sales report.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your email in a simple if statment:

```
Do
DoEvents
If Rows(row_number).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    'Your email function
End If
row_number = row_number + 1
Loop Until row_number = 227
```

This way, if your row is hidden (ie. filtered) it will skip that row. I moved the row_number to the end assuming that you are starting at row 6. This will prevent the code from skipping line 6 because line 7 was hidden.

Comment: this is great. thanks but i need all the filtered data shown in different rows in one mail and not sending 10 emails to the same person.

Comment: Move the `MsgBox mail_body_message` & `Call SendEmail(...)` outside of your loop. In their place put: 
`mail_body_message = mail_body_message & vbNewLine`
This will allow the loop to continue building up your body string and only send the email once it has looped through all visible cells.

Comment: when i put MsgBox mail_body_message & Call SendEmail(...) outside of the loop, it gives me error asking for email address. even though they are already there.

Comment: Is your function `Call SendEmail(Worksheets("Sheet").Range("K" & row_number), "Outstanding 
Invoices", mail_body_message)` is still referencing row_number? If it is you will need to adjust this to a static string or a static reference in order to only send 1 email.